# GEOPACKAGING ERROR ON QGIS: Cannot View all layers in the geopackage on another device

Tags: qgis

As a part of my QGIS assignment, I have been asked to collect coordinates of my university campus. I am supposed to draw polygons over different parts of the campus, add the coordinates and Geo package the assignment as our submission. I am unable to view all the geopackaged layers( only half of them are visible) on another device. I am following these steps:

1. Selecting Create New Layer and then New Geo packaged Layer
2. Saving the file, selecting the geometry type (polygon, line string), naming the layer(Table Name), adding fields to its attribute and then saving it.
3. After creating the polygon/line, when I want to go to make another layer, I follow the same steps (1) and (2) and I get the option of add layers or overwrite. I click add layers to the first geopackage file saved on the laptop.

After sending this geopackage, all layers are not visible when I open in another device(followed all steps of forming a new connection and so forth)

Comment: What happens if you select the layer in the layers panel, right click and choose zoom to layer?  Do you see your data then?  If so, this would indicate a projection problem.

Comment: Maybe your changes are still in the .wal and .shm files. Read about Write Ahead Logging from https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html. If .wal and .shm files exist, the edits have not been committed into the main .gpkg file yet. Removing the layers from the QGIS project should trigger checkpointing. When .wal and .shm files have disappered the main file is up to date.

Comment: Are you using Qfield?